# Is there any way to upload an entire folder of image datasets into google colab from google drive or local

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I have been working on a project regarding the alzheimers and I want to run the code on google colab. I used the `from google.colab import drive` and `drive.mount('\content\drive')` to import the files, and I passed the shareable link as a variable, it throws a `'file not found'` error or a `'Transport endpoint is not connected'` error. Kindly let me know if one can import an entire folder full of image datasets into google colab, if there is any way of doing so

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

[the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbgQT.png)

Answer (score 0):

[`ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) accepts a directory path as the first argument (`directory`); you cannot pass a URL to this method.

You mentioned that you used `drive.mount()` to mount Google Drive to Colab's virtual machine, and that's a good start! From there:

1. Locate the dataset using Colab's file browser ( folder icon on the sidebar). The contents of your Google Drive is mounted to `/content/drive/MyDrive`.
2. Copy the path to the dataset root (right-click the directory -> `Copy path`)
3. Pass this path to `flow_from_directory()`.

Therefore the working code would be:

```py
train_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory="/content/drive/MyDrive/...", # path to your dataset
    # ...
    # the rest of arguments
    # ...
)
```